# セッションスコープに保存されたオブジェクトは、サーバ側とクライアント側のどちらですか？

Tags: java, jsp

プログラミング経験1年半のものです。 
前回先輩から次のような質問をされました。

**「セッションスコープに保存されたオブジェクトは、サーバ側とクライアント側のどちらですか？」**

サーブレットのセッション管理のことなのかなと思い調べているのですが、正確な答えを確認できていません。HTTPsessionも調べています。

もしわかる方がいらっしゃれば教えて頂きたいと思います。

Answer (score 1):

**他の方からのアドバイスによりこの質問は解決しました！**

保存されたオブジェクトが存在するのは、**サーバ側です。**

サーバはセッションIDという一意な文字列を生成し、このセッションIDに紐付ける形でオブジェクトをサーバ上に保存します。

そして、サーバからクライアントに対して、「あなたのセッションIDはコレですよ。以降の通信ではこのセッションIDを使用してくださいね。」と教えてあげます。

クライアントはサーバから教えてもらったセッションIDを以降の通信(リクエストヘッダ)に乗せて通信を行います。 
サーバはクライアントから送られてくるセッションIDを用いて、以前保存した情報との紐付けを解決します。